# Filtering To Be Displayed Images By Spesific Characters in their file Name

Tags: php

I am using this code to load all `.png` images located in `img` directory but I need to ONLY select and render the images which starting with `ABCDEF` character to be selected and displayed. foe example

```
╔═════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ ABCDEF_seaview.png  ║ will be Selected  ║ 
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ GHIJKL_seaview.png  ║ will be Ignored   ║
╚═════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

here is the code:

```
<?php
    $dirname = "../img/";
    $images = glob($dirname."*.png");
     foreach($images as $image) {
        $filename = basename($image);
        echo '<div class="img-panel">';
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="" alt=""/>';
        echo '</div>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Err, how about `glob($dirname . 'ABCDEF*.png')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check starts with before creating UI.

```
<?php
    $dirname = "../img/";
    $images = glob($dirname."*.png");
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $filename = basename($image);
        if (startsWith($filename, "ABCDEF") {
            echo '<div class="img-panel">';
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="" alt=""/>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    // search backwards starting from haystack length characters from the end
    return $needle === "" || strrpos($haystack, $needle, -strlen($haystack)) !== false;
}
?>
```